# What's new in Prism 8 and 9

Tags: version, prism

Our company has been using Prism 7.x for a few years now.
There is a 'big migration/refactoring' going to happen and I was wondering if is there a "What's new?" document for Prim 8 and 9?

I did try to find it on the different Prism resource sites but had not much luck :(

I would be also interested in finding out

- Which version of Prism did/will add support for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection?
- Is Prism 9 (prerelease version if I understand correctly) 'mature enough' to be used in production software?

Would appreciate your help.

Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list of changes on [github](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases).

You need Prism 9 if your app uses Maui, but Maui itself isn't really mature enough for production use, more like Xamarin Forms in 2014.

Also worth noting, Prism 9 has a paid license now (except for hobbyist use).

Comment: Thanks Haukinger.

There is one more thing in Prism 9 that seems worthy considering:
- Support for the Microsoft .Net DI  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

I am wondering if there is any obstacle in me implementing that in Prism 7?

Comment: I guess, you could create some kind of adapter between `IServiceCollection` and `IContainerRegistry`, but I'm unsure whether functionality can me mapped 1:1, probably you're better off keeping the actual container around and passing it into both worlds separately and use existing adpaters.